# Unmarshalling a Struct containing an array of structs

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I'm trying to get back this struct from a native C library through P/Invoke:

```
struct ndb_mgm_cluster_state 
{
    int no_of_nodes;
    struct ndb_mgm_node_state node_states[1];
};
```

where `ndb_mgm_node_state` is:

```
struct ndb_mgm_node_state {   

    int node_id;

    enum ndb_mgm_node_type   node_type;

    enum ndb_mgm_node_status node_status;

    int start_phase;

    int dynamic_id;

    int node_group;

    int version;

    int connect_count;

    char connect_address[sizeof("000.000.000.000")+1    ];

    int mysql_version;
};
```

The method's signature is:

```
 ndb_mgm_cluster_state* WINAPI wrap_ndb_mgm_get_status(HANDLE handle);
```

All of this is provided by a 3rd party library, so nothing can be changed.
In C# i have the follow definitions:

```
[DllImport("Ndb_CWrapper.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern IntPtr wrap_ndb_mgm_get_status(IntPtr handle);
```

the structures are:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct ndb_mgm_cluster_state {

public int no_of_nodes;

public IntPtr node_states;
};


[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct ndb_mgm_node_state 
{

    public int node_id;

    public ndb_mgm_node_type node_type;

    public ndb_mgm_node_status node_status;

    public int start_phase;

    public int dynamic_id;

    public int node_group;

    public int version;

    public int connect_count;

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
    public string connect_address;

    public int mysql_version;
  };
```

I tried to unmarshal the results without success (i recieve an oddly error (not an Exception) Fatal error execution, can be a CLR bug or a miscall P/invoke.

Obviously the reason is a problem in my P/Invoke call

I tried in this way:
First of all i unmarshalled the `ndb_mgm_cluster_state` structure:

```
var res=(ndb_mgm_cluster_state)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                               tmpPtr, typeof(ndb_mgm_cluster_state));
```

where `IntPtr` is the result of the native call.
Up to this step everything "seems" to be done right, but when i try to unmarshall the `node_states` i get the error:

```
ndb_mgm_node_state tmpNode = (ndb_mgm_node_state)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
 status.node_states, typeof(ndb_mgm_node_state));
```

What can be the problem? I supposed is something related to the strange declaration of `ndb_mgm_cluster_state` because is defined an array of 1 element, but it contain several elements. (the number of elements is in `no_of_nodes`)

**WORKAROUND:**

The only way to let everything work i found is to change a bit the signature, in this way:

```
ndb_mgm_node_state* WINAPI wrap_ndb_mgm_get_status(HANDLE handle,int* length);
```

in C#:

```
[DllImport("Ndb_CWrapper.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern IntPtr wrap_ndb_mgm_get_status(IntPtr handle,out int length);
```

where length contains `no_of_nodes`

the unmarshall will be in this way:

```
IntPtr tmpPtr = wrap_ndb_mgm_get_status(raw,out length);
ndb_mgm_cluster_state tmpRes = new ndb_mgm_cluster_state();
tmpRes.no_of_nodes = length;
tmpRes.node_states = new ndb_mgm_node_state[length];
int step=0;
for (int i = 0; i < tmpRes.no_of_nodes; i++) 
  {
   tmpRes.node_states[i] = (ndb_mgm_node_state)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                         tmpPtr+(step*i),    typeof(ndb_mgm_node_state));
   step = Marshal.SizeOf(tmpRes.node_states[i]);
  }
```

I know the step calculation is odd at the monent, but its not that the point.
there is no way to let the thing work returning directly the `ndb_mgm_cluster_state` struct instead of do all of this?

Comment: If this C# code `public IntPtr node_states;` declares as pointer, this does **not** match this member `struct ndb_mgm_node_state node_states[1];` on the C side, as the latter is an array with one element. There are no pointers here in C.

Comment: The code is compiled with a C++ compiler, when i declared the C# struct with public `ndb_mgm_node_state[1] nodestates` it does not work (even with all sort of MarshalAttribute option i can think of)